# Limits on number of emails that can be sent to "BCC to Salesforce"

Tags: email, emailtosalesforce

I'm working to implement a mass mailer system for a customer, and they'd like to have each outgoing email BCC'd to the unique link that will track it in Salesforce.

My customer may be sending out upwards of 1M emails per day, and would like to include Salesforce as the BCC on all of them so that they can track email activities on their customers.

Does anyone know if there are limits on the number of emails that can be BCC'd to Salesforce? I'm aware of Salesforce's 5000 single send limit, but I don't believe that would apply here.

I've also seen the [limits](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.email_my_email_2_sfdc_considerations.htm&type=5) mentioned in this support article, but I don't see anything on the overall number of activities that can be created. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: good question; there's a limit on cases created by E2C of 1000*licenses up to 1M and email-to-salesforce is roughly equivalent to E2C so I would imagine there must be a limit.